# Problem chaging to new NIC card on venerable server running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, nic

I am trying to add a 10gb NIC card to an ancient Ubuntu server running 18.04 and having difficulty. I am current on apt-get updates, but the server has been running for at least a decade and I believe the networking configuration is now a tangled mess due to changes in Ubuntu during that time.

My current setup is that the server's LOM is set to static IP at 10.0.0.12. I would like to move that IP address to the new NIC card. While it might be nice to have the other NIC still work with some other IP address in the same 10.0.0.x subnet, it's not crucial.

In the output below, enp7s0f0np0 is the fiber 10gb port I'm trying to move to. I want this to be at 10.0.0.12.

eth0 is the old copper gig port I'm trying to move off of. I want this to relinquish 10.0.0.12.

```
stew@argus:~$ ifconfig -a
enp7s0f0np0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.171  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::c665:5865:8783:9f44  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0f:53:24:8a:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15856  bytes 6617218 (6.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2894  bytes 318866 (318.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  

enp7s0f1np1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0f:53:24:8a:11  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.121  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::20f:1fff:fefa:be37  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0f:1f:fa:be:37  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 416  bytes 82839 (82.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 525  bytes 109468 (109.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 413  bytes 149729 (149.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 413  bytes 149729 (149.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:2e:55:4a:8a:6e  txqueuelen 100  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I don't know why enp7s0f0np0 is at 10.0.0.171, which is in my DHCP range. As you can see below in the /etc/network/interfaces file, I've tried to put it static at 10.0.0.6.

```
stew@argus:~$ ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: off (auto)
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

^ Copper gig port

```
stew@argus:~$ ethtool enp7s0f0np0
Settings for enp7s0f0np0:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full 
                                10000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
                                10000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full 
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 255
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x000020f7 (8439)
                               drv probe link ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err hw
        Link detected: yes
```

^ 10Gb fiber port

```
stew@argus:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.121
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-addresses 10.0.0.1

auto enp7s0f0np0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.12
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-addresses 10.0.0.1
```

Here I'm trying to move eth0 off to the side at 10.0.0.121.

It seems like I'm not running Netplan, or, at least, incompletely:

```
stew@argus:~$ cd /etc/netplan/
stew@argus:/etc/netplan$ ls -alg
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  4096 Jun 20 20:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 211 root 16384 Jun 20 20:02 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root   235 May 21 21:24 50-cloud-init.yaml
stew@argus:/etc/netplan$ cat 50-cloud-init.yaml 
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    ens3:
        dhcp4: true
        match:
            macaddress: <redacted for post>
        set-name: ens3
        nameservers:
            addresses: [10.0.0.1, 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, 1.1.0.0]
```

When I attempt this change to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
stew@argus:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet static
#address 10.0.0.121
#netmask 255.255.255.0
#network 10.0.0.0
#broadcast 10.0.0.255
#gateway 10.0.0.1
#dns-addresses 10.0.0.1

auto enp7s0f0np0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.12
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-addresses 10.0.0.1
```

I lose the ability to ssh and ping the server at 10.0.0.12 - or any IP I can think of - but I *CAN* ping outwards from the box.

Again, you should assume that any and every historical Ubuntu network configuration type could be present on this server, it has been in continuous operation for 10+ years. I know about a few types, but I think I must be missing something.

Advice?

Answer (score 0):

auto enp7s0f0np0
iface **enp7s0f0np0** inet static
address 10.0.0.12
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-addresses 10.0.0.1

After a quick glance, it seems maybe you carried over the eth0 instead of the new interface name where I marked above in bold.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem I think.

I followed this tutorial:

https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/netplan-how-to-configure-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-18-04-using-netplan.html, starting at the section "Configure Static IP Address using Netplan".

My netplan directory now looks like this:

```
stew@argus:~$ cd /etc/netplan/
stew@argus:/etc/netplan$ ls -alg
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  4096 Jun 20 22:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 211 root 16384 Jun 20 20:02 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root   384 Jun 20 22:38 01-network-card.yaml
stew@argus:/etc/netplan$ cat 01-network-card.yaml 
network:
        version: 2
        renderer: networkd
        ethernets:
                enp7s0f0np0:
                        dhcp4: no
                        addresses: [10.0.0.12/24]
                        gateway4: 10.0.0.1
                        nameservers:
                                search: [doodle.local]
                                addresses: [10.0.0.1,8.8.8.8]
stew@argus:/etc/netplan$
```

Since I did a

```
apt remove ifupdown
```

as part of the guide I believe my /etc/network/interfaces file is now irrelevant. But thank you @Justus95, your suggestion might indeed have been what was wrong with that setup.